# AutoHotKey: Active Window then MouseMove

Tags: autohotkey

I want to active certain window and then move the mouse to a position relative to the active window's client area. See the code below:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Client
WinActivate, titile
MouseMove, 200, 100
```

The window is actived while the mouse seems not move. But if I change the code order, like:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Client
MouseMove, 200, 100    
WinActivate, titile
```

The window is actived as expect, while the mouse moves, but relative to the last window. I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

After performing,

```
WinActivate, titile
```

try

```
WinWaitActivate, titile
```

so that your code stops until the window is activated

Also try to move

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Client
```

behind the WinWaitActivate command

Depending on your windows/autohotkey version, replace **Client** with **Relative**

Comment: I updated the answer. Post your windows version & autohotkey version if you still have problems

Comment: I try and add sleep, but it doesn't work also. My OS is win10.

Comment: I seems to find the problem. Some common windows will do as expect, while some not. I don' t know why.

Answer (score 1):

1. [`WinActivate`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) does **not** update the [Last Found window](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#LastFoundWindow).
2. You don't need to wait until the window activates to move the mouse pointer.

Try:

```
; Its location doesn't matter so long as it comes before mouse movements.
CoordMode Mouse, Client

; WinExist ensures the Last Found window is updated.
WinActivate % "ahk_id " WinExist("titile")

; Better than MouseMove in a number of aspects.
SendInput {Click 200 100 0}
```

Comment: @ johnlee, I hasve tried your method, it works on common windows except some. Maybe there are some tricks on some game windows.

Comment: @foo: That's weird as I've found no such instances. 1. Make sure you're using the right WinTitle strings. 2. Some windows change their titles when full-screened. 3. Does the mouse pointer move at all? If not, try `SendPlay` in place of `SendInput`.

Comment: That's weird indeed. I have tried but it doesn't work. Any mouse operation wouldn't work after this very game window actiaved  (while MsgBox would). I have try AutoIt, the same result is got

Comment: I found the window class isTfrmMain which developed by Delphi , I don't know if it  matters